# Fatal Python error

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

I'm having a problem with my python installation, it was working fine. I'm not even sure what the cause of the problem is.

I keep getting the following error when I run any python related command on command line:

```
Error:

    Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/nkosana/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/io.py", line 52, in <module>
      File "/Users/nkosana/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/abc.py", line 3

        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
    Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: What does `python --version` report? Any chance the python version and libraries are mismatched?

Comment: El Capitan version 10.11.1

Comment: @Fatalerror the version is Python 3.4.2, not sure I have not installed python  version recently

Comment: The error message is claiming that abc.py, line 3 is corrupt.  Take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem trying to use Python 3 in an environment that already had python2 basically what I realized in my case is that the python3 tried to import materials python2.

My solution was to unset $PYTHONPATH

Comment: Then don't or format this as an answer. You are allowed to be wrong when you answer.

Comment: I had the same problem trying to use Python 3 in an environment that already had python2 basically what I realized in my case is that the python3 tried to import materials python2.